# Why does an explicit cast to ‘decimal’ call an explicit operator to ‘long’?

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

Consider the following code:

```
class Program
{
    public static explicit operator long(Program x) { return 47; }

    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new Program();
        Console.WriteLine((decimal) x);
    }
}
```

To my surprise, this outputs `47`; in other words, the `explicit operator long` is called even though the cast is to `decimal`.

Is there something in the C# spec that explicitly says that this should happen (if so, where exactly) or is this the result of some other rule(s) I’m missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I’ve found the answer. First of all, there is the concept of one type being **encompassed** by another, which is defined in *6.4.3 Evaluation of user-defined conversions* as follows:

> If a standard implicit conversion (§6.3.1) exists from a type A to a
>   type B, and if neither A nor B are *interface-types*, then A is said to
>   be **encompassed by** B, and B is said to **encompass** A.

*6.3.1 Standard implicit conversions* states that “Implicit numeric conversions (§6.1.2)” are a standard implicit conversion, and *6.1.2 Implicit numeric conversions* in turn defines an implicit conversion from `long` to `decimal`. Therefore, `long` is **encompassed by** `decimal`.

Next, *6.4.5 User-defined explicit conversions* states that one of the stages in determining whether an explicit conversion is applicable is to:

> Find the set of applicable user-defined and lifted conversion
>   operators, U. This set consists of the user-defined and lifted
>   implicit or explicit conversion operators declared by the classes or
>   structs in D that convert from a type encompassing or encompassed by S
>   to a type encompassing or encompassed by T. If U is empty, the
>   conversion is undefined and a compile-time error occurs.

Here, `D` refers to the result of an earlier step which, in this case, contains only `decimal`, `Program` and `object`. Thus, the set `U` will contain the `Program`-to-`long` explicit operator I declared because `long` is encompassed by `decimal` (as we found earlier).

One of the next steps selects `long` as the *most specific target type,* `TX`.

Finally, the last step in that same algorithm states:

> Finally, apply the conversion:
>
> - If S is not SX, then a standard explicit conversion from S to SX is performed.
> - The most specific user-defined conversion operator is invoked to convert from SX to TX.
> - If TX is not T, then a standard explicit conversion from TX to T is performed.

Here, `S` and `SX` are both `Program`, so the first part does nothing. `TX` was selected to be `long` and `T` is the target type, `decimal`, so the last part executes the standard conversion from `long` to `decimal`.

Comment: All very interesting. Thanks for sharing. I'd just started to look through the spec myself so you saved me a lot of time. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The only explanation I can think of is that the compiler is smart enough to realize there is an implicit operator that will convert long to decimal, that it can use to satisfy the explicit conversion between Program and decimal when Program can only convert to long.

**EDIT:** Here we are; conversions between numeric types are built into the language spec:

> 6.1.2 Implicit numeric conversions
>
> The implicit numeric conversions are:
>
> ·         From sbyte to short, int, long, float, double, or decimal.
>
> ·         From byte to short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, float,
>   double, or decimal.
>
> ·         From short to int, long, float, double, or decimal.
>
> ·         From ushort to int, uint, long, ulong, float, double, or
>   decimal.
>
> ·         From int to long, float, double, or decimal.
>
> ·         From uint to long, ulong, float, double, or decimal.
>
> ·         **From long to float, double, or decimal.**
>
> ·         From ulong to float, double, or decimal.
>
> ·         From char to ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, float, double,
>   or decimal.
>
> ·         From float to double.
>
> Conversions from int, uint, long, or ulong to float and from long or
>   ulong to double may cause a loss of precision, but will never cause a
>   loss of magnitude. The other implicit numeric conversions never lose
>   any information.
>
> There are no implicit conversions to the char type, so values of the
>   other integral types do not automatically convert to the char type.

So, when converting between Program and decimal, C# knows that it can implicitly convert from any numeric type to decimal, so when performing this explicit conversion, it will look for any operator that can get Program to a numeric type.

What would be interesting to see is, what happens if you also put in an explicit conversion to, say, uint, that returned 48? Which one would the compiler pick?

Comment: In answer to your last question if you have a uint conversion to it still uses long but I suspect that is some inbuilt precedence there. And I'm not entirely sure that what you quoted is strictly relevant. I'm not sure that it says you are allowed to convert from a non-numeric to a numeric before doing that conversion.

Comment: Interesting if you compile it and look at it with a tool like reflector, it ends up creating IL that does something like `Console.WriteLine((decimal) ((long) x));` The C# compiler explicitly casts to long first, then decimal.

Comment: "So, when converting between Program and decimal, C# knows that it can implicitly convert from *any numeric type* to decimal..." Not quite. Notice that float only goes to double, and double goes to nothing.

Comment: @Anthony: Given strong typing, does the IL for a 'normal' implicit conversion also appear as an explicit conversion?

Comment: @Timwi: it may be enough that the spec simply does not define the behavior in that scenario, and that it is up to the compiler implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but of course I already knew about the numeric conversions. That doesn’t answer the question, which is about a conversion from a type (in the example, `Program`) that is not numeric. By now I’ve found the answer and posted it separately.

Comment: @Marc, I'm not an IL guy. But in this case, the IL invokes the explicit conversion to long and the implicit conversion to decimal. Via LinqPad: `IL_0007: call UserQuery+Program.op_Explicit IL_000C: call System.Decimal.op_Implicit IL_0011: call System.Console.WriteLine`